# Mean Squared error for complex Weibull Model

Tags: least-squares

Can anyone give me a hand here. I have been trying to solve this problem for weeks, but lead me no where. I want to find the roots of the following function

$f(d_1, d_2)=$$\sum_{i=0}^n{[P(e_i)-P_i^L]^2+[P(e_i)-P_i^u]^2}$$

Where:

$P(e_i)=\frac{1-e^-(\frac{a_i}{d_2})^d_1}{1-e^-(\frac{b}{d_2})^d_1}$

I can take the derivative of the function with respect to both d1 and d2 without any problem, but I don't know which kind of numerical method to apply. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please

Comment: Would it be possible to linearize the function P(ei)? I try to do that and couldn't see a way out either.

Comment: Never mind! I solved my problem!